# Replace complex line using sed in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

how do I replace

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profileDmgr/bin/startManager.sh
```

with

```
"/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profileDmgr/bin/startManager.sh -timeout 10"
```

using sed command

Comment: Why replace the whole string? Why not just append the new bits?

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's,/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profileDmgr/bin/startManager.sh,"/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profileDmgr/bin/startManager.sh -timeout 1",
```

This uses commas as separators instead of slashes. I've left the input and output to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profileDmgr/bin/startManager.sh|"& -timeout 10"|' YourFile
```

use & to avoid repeating same huge pattern